# Is instantiating a GUID in Entity Framework Core bad practice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, guid

If I have a model with a key of type `Guid`, is it bad practise to set the ID explicitly in the constructor?

I know it will be set implicitly by Entity Framework, but will anything bad happen (perhaps performance wise) from setting it explicitly?

Example:

```
class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

I'm thinking a `Guid` is backed up by a sequential ID in SQL server, and if I set a value explicitly, I suppose I will decrease indexing performance because it will no longer be sequential?

I have not been able to find an answer on this and I am highly curious about it.

Comment: Test it yourself. Create 100000 entities and let EF assign the GUID. Profile a few queries against it. Wipe the table, then create 100000 entities with a GUID you new up yourself and profile that. I will assume (and it is only an assumption), that there'll be no difference.

Comment: guids aren't sequential though. They tend to be if generated by the same system, but that seems foolish to rely on.

Comment: The SQL datatype for a .Net Guid is a [`uniqueidentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see a design flaw rather than a performance problem: models shouldn't generate their `id`. It's out of their responsibility. Repositories do so in the `Add` method.

`Guid` can be generated in many ways: for example, it can be random or sequential. There're different algorithms to generate them either way. Therefore, you're closing your choices to just one.

And you're forcing the moment on which the model `id` is assigned: you mighn't want this in order to delay its assignment until the model may need to be persisted. *For example, a zero `Guid`  may be useful to know that some model isn't persistent yet.*